# How do I get my data scraped cleaned up in text without HTML/TAG?

Tags: python-3.7

I'm trying to scrape this website(bottom table) https://www.eia.gov/dnav/ng/hist/rngwhhdD.htm which I already got the code so far. I need help with cleaning up the data scraped. (I just need the text and remove HTML code/tags)

(This code beneath works) 
(I'm doing this in Jupyter notebook btw)

I've been trying ".text" and ".strip" but no luck so far.

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv


#open page and grab html
my_url = ('https://www.eia.gov/dnav/ng/hist/rngwhhdD.htm')
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close


#HTML parser
page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')


#Find table
soup = page_soup.findAll("td",{"class":{"B6","B3"}})

#Print table
print(soup)
```

I expect to print everything without the HTML/tag codes. Just clean text in columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following code which meet your requirement. BTW, you can read the [`BeautifulSoup Document`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and write some code to test your thinking when you have trouble. Hope it's helpful for you.

```py
# There is no need to use alias here which maybe make confusion later, although you can do it
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

# open page and grab html
my_url = ('https://www.eia.gov/dnav/ng/hist/rngwhhdD.htm')
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# HTML parser
page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')

table = []

# Find table
ele_table = page_soup.find("table", summary="Henry Hub Natural Gas Spot Price (Dollars per Million Btu)")
# traverse table
col_tag = 'th'
ele_rows = ele_table.find_all('tr', recursive=False)
for ele_row in ele_rows:
    row = []
    ele_cols = ele_row.find_all(col_tag, recursive=False)
    for ele_col in ele_cols:
        # use empty string for no data column
        content = ele_col.string.strip() if ele_col.string else ''
        row.append(content)
    col_tag = 'td'
    # just save row with data
    if any(row):
        table.append(row)

# print table
for row in table:
    print('\t'.join(row))
```